# Sum of probability density functions

Tags: probability-distributions

If $A_1$ is random variable exponentially distributed  with pdf $f(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ when $t \geq0$ and $0$ when $t< 0$.

Let $A_2$ be random variable that is independent of $A_1$ but it has the same pdf as $A_1$. What is the pdf of $B=A_1+A_2$.

And if introduce third independent random variable $A_3$ with the same pdf as the others. What is pdf of $C=A_1+A_2+A_3$

So from the theory I know that pdf of the sum of two continous random variables is the convolution of their own pdf's. So

\begin{align} 
B=f_{z}(z)&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z-t)f(t) dt \\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{z} \lambda e^{-\lambda z+\lambda t} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt \\
&=\lambda^2 \int\limits_{0}^{z} e^{-\lambda z} dt \\
&=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z} \int\limits_{0}^{z} 1 dt \\
&=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z} z
\end{align}
When $z\geq0$. $\int f(z-t)f(t)=0$ when $z<0$

So then C should be with the same idea when $\tau \geq 0$
\begin{align}
C=f_{\tau} (\tau) &=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\tau-z)f(z) dz \\
&=\lambda^4\int\limits_0^{\tau} z(\tau-z) e^{-\lambda \tau+\lambda z}  e^{-\lambda z} dz \\
&=\lambda^4 e^{-\lambda \tau}\int\limits_0^{\tau} z\tau-z^2 dz \\
&=\lambda^4 e^{-\lambda \tau} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \tau^3 -\frac 13 \tau^3 \right) \\
&=\frac{\lambda^4 \tau^3 e^{-\lambda \tau}}{6}
\end{align}

And the integral should be zero when $\tau<0$. Correct?

Comment: For which values of $t$ is $f(z - t) = 0$?

Comment: Isn't it when zero when $(z-t)\to \infty$ ?

Comment: Do I have to do the integral in parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity let's do it with $\lambda=1$.

Then if $z\geq 0$: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(z-t\right)f\left(t\right)dt=\int_{0}^{z}e^{-\left(z-t\right)}e^{-t}dt=\int_{0}^{z}e^{-z}dt=e^{-z}\int_{0}^{z}dt=e^{-z}z$$
 Note that the integrand $f\left(z-t\right)f\left(t\right)$ equals $0$ if $t\notin(0,z)$.

Secondly if $z<0$: $$\int f\left(z-t\right)f\left(t\right)dt=0$$  This because the integrand has value $0$ for each $t$.

Comment: Okey nice. Why does my integral with the infinities rather than $t\in [0,z]$ doesn't get discrete value? Can't I do it that way?

Comment: You are assuming that $f(z-t)f(t)=e^{-(z-t)}e^t$ for **each** $t\geq0$. That is not the case. That is the essential mistake you make. On its own your method to find the PDF is okay.

Comment: Ahhhhh! I think I got it. The density function only exist for $t$ values in $[0,z]$

Comment: Can the pdf of the sum of three random variables be done like  I did on my edited post?

Comment: It is not right to *change* a post. If you want to know then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of variable exponentially distributed is not  $f(t)=\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$ but $\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$ if $t \ge 0$ and $0$ if not.
So since $t$ and $z-t$ should be $> 0, B=f_z(z)=\int_0^{z}f(z−t)f(t)dt$.